Can't access webserver from WAN after Opnsense upgrade
I finally decided to upgrade my opnsense box after a couple of years of deferring and, in the heat of the moment, forgot to double-check I had configuration backups. After the upgrade to      OPNsense 24.1.8-amd64 (FreeBSD 13.2-RELEASE-p11), there were some issues with LAN clients accessing the WAN that I solved by resetting to default settings. (I have not modified much, so it’s somewhat trivial to add back aliases and rules.)
Now, however, I am facing a problem where port forwarded services do not work. I am running Nginx Proxy Manager to handle the various web services on my LAN and the setup has served me well for years. I have made no changes to Nginx PM, to my port forwarding rules (see below), or to the individual services and their boxes. Put simply, everything was working 100% without issue until I foolishly upgraded.
webserver port forward rule
Interface  Proto   Address Ports   Address     Ports   IP         Ports
WAN        TCP     *       *       WAN address 80,443  webserver  80,443
I suspect the issue is a double NAT issue with my godawful BGW320-505 gateway. I have had this configured to IP passthrough mode without issue for years. But, after the Opnsense upgrade (and defaults), I did notice that my interfaces display what looks to be an upstream-gateway assigned IP address. Previously, my upstream WAN gateway was the IP address of the BGW320-505 box.
System: Gateways: Configuration shows my Interface WAN_DHCP Gateway as the IP address of the BGW320-505 (192.168.1.254) while Interfaces shows my WAN IP as 192.168.1.108.
Despite all of the above, there seems to be some weird DNS issue/NAT issue. The strongest example I’ve uncovered of this is, from my LAN directly accessing my WAN IP. While this should show me my http-facing webserver, the request times out for a while then eventually resolves to a 404 page but–and this is the bizarre part–not before appending :440 (my webgui port for Opnsense) to the WAN IP in the address bar. (Note that this does not occur when accessing my direct IP address from exterior to the network.) I’m hoping that is the key to solving this but, after more than 15 hours spent researching this and trying various solutions available on forums/reddit/etc., I have not found anything to work.
I have tried to restore my previous port forward rules, but though they appear to be configured properly, I did not have any success.
I've also reviewed a ton of write-ups about IP Passthrough, double NAT issues, Opnsense configurations with IP Passthrough, and more, but no matter what--nothing helps.
I have also tried turnkey nginx and lighttpd installs to test if the nginx configurations (which I have not touched since the Opnsense upgrade) were the issue. Nothing helped here, either.
Update 1: I have switched the BGW320-505 gateway from Manual IP Passthrough to DHCP-S Fixed. This has resulted in my System: Gateways: Configuration changing to show my Interface WAN_DHCP Gateway as the my WAN IP minus the last digit (e.g., X.X.X.1) while Interfaces shows my WAN IP (e.g., X.X.X.Y). Re-checking open ports through online tools shows most (but not all?) of my ports as accessible, but I am still unable to actually reach any of their services either on WAN or LAN.

What IP is assigned to OpenSense now? Also have you rebooted both the gateway and OpenSense since you changed GW to DCHP? If GW was in passthru, perhaps the OpenSense needs a public IP assigned to it if that's how it had been working before the changes.

Also read over https://docs.opnsense.org/manual/nat.html and see about NAT reflection or One-to-one NAT configurations it mentions. I'd have to play with the router and FW configs myself to know for sure but if ISP GW is passthrough, assign the public IP to the FW, as that may be what's needed. I assume you have some security rules to go along with the NAT/port forwarding rules but ensure traffic is not being blocked  at the security policy level of the FW. I'd have the web server in a DMZ if it were me and poke holes from DMZ to LAN as needed if any or LAN to DMZ if applicable for your FW.

The IP assigned to Opnsense at the moment, per Interfaces: WAN is my expected WAN IP. I have rebooted both the GW and Opnsense several times for each of the configurations above (indeed, this step seems to be required to get the WAN IP to be recognized and correctly assigned to Opnsense).

It should not if you passthru the ISP GW and manually assign the FW the public IP address. I can't remember if it needs to be a specific one if you have more than one public IP though. Perhaps when you do that and then config the one-to-one NAT and/or NAT reflection, that may get it back to the original configs before the upgrade. What was server DHCP before the OpenSense upgrade. Once IPs are assigned manually in passthru, configure DHCP somewhere to point LAN to proper gateway to get to OpenSense I'm assuming.
